# Scheduling jobs in python

Tags: python-2.7, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way in python, through which I could schedule a task on daily basis between specific hours. I found some schedulers, but I could not see such functionality.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use celery,http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also user Flask-APScheduler:

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

for example:

```
import os
import logging
import mylibrary
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

import app

# APPLICATION SETTINGS
config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG', 'default')
app = app.create_app(config_name)
manager = Manager(app)

[...]     

# SCHEDULED JOB
sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(mylibrary.job1,'interval',seconds=60)
sched.start()

[...]
```